# convert a 2d array into a csv file in php

Tags: php, arrays, file

I'm try to convert a 2d array into a csv file . but i got errors

array to string conversion in line 7

here is my code

```
<?php
$export_arr =$_POST['dataString'];
$fp = fopen('file.xls', 'w');
foreach ( $export_arr as $line ) {
//$val = explode(",", $line);
fputcsv($fp, $export_arr);
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

i want put the values in each cell in the xls file

any ideas

Comment: You probably meant to do: `fputcsv($fp, $line);`

Answer (score 3):

Change this line:

```
fputcsv($fp, $export_arr);
```

To:

```
fputcsv($fp, $line);
```

Comment: my array is like this [1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4], how can i separate this inner array into separate value. help me

Comment: @Max25 - Is there a problem with that? `fputcsv` accepts an array as an argument, so looping through an array of arrays, should give it just what it needs. Or am I missing something?

Comment: `$export_arr =$_POST['dataString'];

$fp = fopen('file.xls', 'w');
    foreach ($export_arr as $fields) {
  $val =explode(',',$fields);
        fputcsv($fp, $val);
    }
    fclose($fp);`   but i got a error array to string conversion error

Comment: @Max25 - Check out the example here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php. They're looping through a 2d array and dumping it into a file, just like you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
fputcsv($fp, $line);
```